# How to send scraped data to a page but without waiting for the page to load?

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am showing some scraped data on my Django website.. The data is changing a couple times every hour so it needs to be updated. I am using Beautiful Soup to scrape the data, then im sending it to the view and passing it in a context dictionary to present it on a website.
The problem is that scraping function takes some time to work and because of it the website is not loading until the function does its work. How can I make it load faster? There is no API on the data webstie.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of your algorithm, if it is an algorithm that goes through a lot of elements that can be or not updated you can save some attribute for not enter in the element. It's a first thought if you show the algorithm maybe we can give you a better answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a hourly scrape task using cron or [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/), store the result into the result into a database and serve your data from there.